# Como comparar datatime com uma data

Tags: php, data, datetime

Estou com um problema no meu sistema de login, eu quero por sistema de validade porem não estou conseguindo comparar a datatime atual com a datatime de expiração recebida.

Tentei usar o seguinte código e não funcionou:

```
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);
$query = "select usuario from usuario where usuario = '{$usuario}' and senha = md5('{$senha}')";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $resultado = $conexao->query($consulta);
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($_SESSION['usuario'] == $row['usuario'])
            $id = $row['usuario_id'];
            $dateTime = new DateTime();
            $sql1 = "UPDATE usuario SET last_ip='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', last_date='".$dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'  WHERE usuario_id='".$id."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql1)

            $d2 = strtotime($row['exp']); # recebendo expiração no caso (2020-04-02 00:00:00)
            $d1 = strtotime($dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); # recebendo nova data

            if($d1 >= $d2){ # tentando comparar...
                unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
                header('Location: index.php');
                $_SESSION['codigo2'] = 0;
                exit();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se está usando [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), não tem porque misturar com [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Também não há motivo para transformar o `DateTime` em string (usando [`format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)), só para passar essa string para `strtotime`.

Basta transformar a string que contém a data de expiração em um `DateTime`, usando [`createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), e compará-la com a data atual:

```
$hoje = new DateTime();
$data_expiracao = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-04-02 00:00:00');

if ($data_expiracao < $hoje) {
    // expirou
} else {
    // não expirou
}
```

---

Lembrando que a comparação leva em conta o horário também, e `new DateTime()` criará um `DateTime` contendo o horário atual.

Se quer a comparação independente do horário, levando em conta somente o dia, basta setar ambas as datas para o mesmo horário. Ex:

```
$hoje = new DateTime();
$hoje->setTime(0, 0); // setar horário para meia-noite
$data_expiracao = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-04-02 15:00:00');
$data_expiracao->setTime(0, 0);
```

Comment: Não resolvido :(, mesmo assim não consegui comparar as ambas DATAS

Comment: @GustavoAlves Como eu não tenho acesso ao seu banco de dados, tudo que posso fazer é testar com os dados que vc forneceu (ou seja, a string `"2020-04-02 00:00:00"`), e com esses dados a comparação funciona. Se não funcionou então tem mais algum detalhe em outros pontos do código, pois para criar as datas e compará-las é só fazer o que mostrei aí.